# Occupancy and financial status affidavit

Tags: united-states, mortgage

We refinanced our house a month ago and now my wife has found a different house she likes and wants to buy it and we were going to use my VA eligibility to buy the new house and once we move in sell the existing house.  The only problem is we signed this affidavit for the re-fi which we currently live in and we intend on moving to the new house, fix this one up and sell it.  My loan officer says the Va might require a release from this affidavit.  The affidavit states a lender may not refuse unless the request is unreasonable.  Thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm assuming this affidavit states that you are using/ will use the home you just refinanced as your primary residence since the title talks about occupancy.  Is that the only thing the affidavit states?  Does it provide a timeline (i.e. you will use the home as your primary residence for at least 6 months)?

Comment: @tom beheler - Can you clarify your question a little? This is more of a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum. You'll need to frame this as an answerable question.

Comment: Why would you use VA eligibility.  VA loans are a bad deal, much better to go conventional.  In some cases even FHA loans are better than VA.